# interpretation of ACF & PACF plots

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

First, apologies in case the question is pretty basic.
Can anyone help me interpret the ACF/PACF plots to identify the values of AR and MA in ARIMA model?

My data set is network traffic in an office which means that it has seasonality of 168 points (hourly aggregation). This is because the traffic on all same days is similar (eg. All Monday's sees heavy traffic)

graph acf and pacf
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your data was non-stationary, the differenced ACF and PACF plots are the ones you should look at. Judging from the graphs you provided, the difference ACF shows a significant lag at 1 and it is positive in value, so consider adding AR(1) term to your model, that is for ARIMA, use p=1 and a q=0, because there is no significant negative correlation at lags 1 and above.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding AR(p)=2 and MA(q)=1

Answer (score 0):

AR(p)=2 and MA(q)=1

Please read this blog

https://arauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_choose_terms.html

Answer (score 0):

After differencing , check if data is stationary or not using ADF or KPSS test
if stationary then AR(p) = 2 and MA(q) = 1 is a good starting point.
but you can include higher lags if it reduces the prediction error on  test data.

If data is not-stationary even after differencing then ,
These ACF and PACF plot cannot be used to find the correct order of ARIMA process.
therefore you need to make the data stationary using simple differencing or/and different transformations like log , Sqrt,Cbrt , simple differencing and combination of these.